# Find the equivalent infinitesimal of $\{na_n-2\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1>0$ and $a_{n+1}=\ln(1+a_n)$ for $n=1,\,2,\cdots$. Find the equivalent infinitestimal of $\{na_n-2\}$.

It's easy to check that $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$ and $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. From Stolz's formula, we can prove that $\lim na_n=2$. But how to find the equivalent infinitestimal of $\{na_n-2\}$?

Comment: What is "equivalent infinitesimal" supposed to mean? $\displaystyle n\,a_n-2\sim\frac23\,\frac{\ln n}n$, if that's what you have in mind.

Comment: Yes. But how to find $\frac{2}{3}\frac{\ln n}{n}$?

Comment: With paper and pencil, so it's not acceptable for 90% of those who ask questions, here.

Comment: Can you give any hint?

Comment: Why not, what about $$\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}=\frac{a_n-\ln(1+a_n)}{a_n\,\ln(1+a_n)}\to\frac12?$$